# How to output a curve type object from Geometry Nodes?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I could not find a way to output a curve.
For example, I made an Arc primitive and want to use it with Follow Path constraint.

[image]

However, the output options have only the geometry type, which is as far as I understand mesh.

[image]

Since the output data is curve, it seems the modifier stack does not allow to apply the Geometry Node tree.

[image]

[image]

So I can't even convert the mesh to curve outside the Geometry Node tree.

Is there a workaround or some magic to solve that problem?

Comment: Is your base object a mesh object or a curve object ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Woe.png You can't change the type of an object using geometry nodes, so if you output a curve from a GN modifier on a mesh object and try to apply it, it won't work. You can convert your curve to an edge mesh with a curve to mesh node with no profile https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKJR7.png

Comment: You can apply the Geometry Nodes modifier only to objects that are a mesh, not to curves. To do this, you would simply have to use a mesh as a base and use and ultimately apply the Geometry Nodes modifier there. However: The actual problem of getting a curve in the end remains unsolved and is currently not solvable. You can use the curves created with GN within the stack (for example with another GN modifier), but for any further processing only the mesh will be available.